# Why ,when and where we will use stored procedures, views and functions?

Tags: sql-server

I often use a stored procedure for data access purpose but don't know which one is best - a view or a stored procedure or a function?

Please tell me which one of the above is best for data access purpose and why it is best, list down the reason with the example please.

I searched Google to learn which one is best but got no expected answer

Answer (score 3):

**View**

A view is a “virtual” table consisting of a `SELECT` statement, by means of “virtual”

I mean no physical data has been stored by the view -- only the definition of the view is stored inside the database; unless you materialize the view by putting an index on it.

1. By definition you can not pass parameters to the view
2. NO DML operations (e.g. `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`) are allowed inside the view; ONLY `SELECT` statements.

Most of the time, view encapsulates complex joins so it can be reusable in the queries or stored procedures. It can also provide level of isolation and security by hiding sensitive columns from the underlying tables.

**Stored procedure**

A stored procedure is a group of Transact-SQL statements compiled into a single execution plan or in other words saved collection of Transact-SQL statements.

A stored procedure:

- accepts parameters
- can NOT be used as building block in a larger query
- can contain several statements, loops, IF ELSE, etc.
- can perform modifications to one or several tables
- can NOT be used as the target of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement

A view:

- does NOT accept parameters
- can be used as building block in a larger query
- can contain only one single SELECT query
- can NOT perform modifications to any table
- but can (sometimes) be used as the target of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

**Functions**

Functions are subroutines made up of one or more Transact-SQL statements that can be used to encapsulate code for reuse

There are three types (scalar, table valued and inline mutlistatement)  UDF and each of them server different purpose you can read more about  functions or UDF in BOL

UDF has a big limitation; by definition it cannot change the state of the database. What I mean by this you cannot perform data manipulation operation inside UDF (INSERT, UPDATE , DELETE) etc.

Answer (score 0):

SP are good for doing DDL statements that you can't do with functions. SP and user defined functions accept parameters and can returns values but they can't do the same statements.

User defined functions can only do DML statements.

View doesn't accept parameters, and only accept DML statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it very short and straight.

When you are accessing data from different tables and don't want to pass parameter use **View**.

When you want to perform DML statement go for **Function**.

When you want to perform DDL statement go for **Stored Procedure**.

Rest is upon your knowledge and idea hit in your mind at particular point of time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below information will help you to understand the use of the SQL procedure, view, and function.

**Stored Procedure -** Stored Procedure can be used for any database operation like insert, update, delete and fetch which you mentioned that you are already using.

**View -** View only can be used to fetch the data but it has limitations as you can't pass the parameters to the view. e.g. filter the data based on the passed parameter

**Function -** Function usually used for a specific operation like you have many in-built SQL server functions also for the date, for math, for string manipulation etc.

Answer (score 0):

And for performance reasons many would argue 
- avoid functions (especially scalar) if possible

It's easier to tweak stored procedures (query plans) and views

IMO, View (and Indexed View) are just Fancier SELECT
Stored Procedure are versatile as you can transform/manipulate within